# Convert root filesystem from ext3 to reiserfs in centos

Tags: centos, reiserfs

When running `df -T`:

```
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/hda1     ext3   1417219800   1197276 1342870552   1% /
tmpfs        tmpfs     4150720         0   4150720   0% /dev/shm
```

How to convert `/dev/hda1` to reiserfs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "convert". You can backup your datas, format to reiserfs and then restore your backup.

Comment: Take an external hard drive, boot on an USB distro (to not use your standard ext3 FS), mount both drives, rsync all from old to new, umount old, then mkfs.reiserfs on old, mount empty old, then rsync from new to old

Comment: The usb drive will need to be formatted in ext3 or reiserfs to work, not fat or ntfs.

Comment: The USB drive must be formated in ext3 or reiserfs, right.